# Autocorrelation Values for Stationary Process

Tags: time-series, self-study, forecasting, autocorrelation

I'm doing a self study out of Box, Jenkins, Reinsal, Ljung - Time Series Analysis Forecasting and Control.  Problem 2.2 has me stuck (it seems so simple) it asks:

State whether or not a stationary stochastic process can have the following values of autocorrelations: 
$$a) \ \rho_1 = .8 \quad \rho_2=0.55\quad  \rho_k = 0 \quad k>2$$
$$b) \ \rho_1 = .8 \quad \rho_2 = .28 \quad \rho_k = 0 \quad k>2$$

I'm trying to get some intuition for this.  I can't see any reason where there would be restrictions on the autocorrelation function or what values it may take which probably exposes a big hole in my understanding of the chapter.  Any advice/intuition/solutions are welcome.

Comment: You need to add the self study tag.

Comment: Did you read about the roots of the characteristic polynomial? Stationarity for AR processes depend on whether or not the roots of the characteristic polynomial fall inside the unity circle.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Thanks, I think this points me in the right direction.